# on page refresh, need to get values of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I fill the input's and hit refresh button, I could not get the values of input in jquery.

How can get them without using cookies?

Comment: please add example buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think so. Where you want to store the input data?

```
window.onunload = function(){ ;}
```

Using this you have to store data some where, you decide. IE provides, some browser memory to store such data for the page, you can use that. I do not remember exact syntax (probably window.external), and not sure about other browsers

Sample code (IE only)

```
<SCRIPT>
function fnSaveForm(){
   window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(oForm);
}
window.onunload = function(){fnSaveForm();}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are not able to retrieve them in this case without using some sort of storage like a local storage, a cookie, etc.. 
Why would you need such a behavior?

Comment: since one field fills the others with ajax, when I hit refresh, I want to fill these again.

Answer (score 1):

You can not "get" them without storing them somehow.

You can store them either on the client (via cookies or HTML5 local storage) or on the server in a session data or other persistence mechanism (via AJAX call)